# need to use PLSQL to insert distinct rows

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, plsql

I need to take some data from Table A, use some logic, and then insert one or more rows into Table B.  I have a PLSQL block that brings in data from Table A with a cursor, performs all the logic required, and inserts the required rows.

The problem is there are duplicate rows in Table B - it's the nature of the beast.  But I need the final result to be a Table B with no duplicates.

It's Oracle so temporary tables are bad form - what's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you have?

Comment: Are "duplicates" happening because there are no constraints preventing it, or are the rows are only considered as duplicates based on a subset of columns?

Comment: I'd have to see some actual code to know for sure, but it might be possible that BULK operations can help: http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bulk_insert.html  You might be able to use `SELECT * BULK COLLECT` to write a query that filters out duplicates... it might depend on the nature and structure of your data as well, but it might work.

Comment: How complicated is the logic? If you can fit it all into one query, you can just do a `INSERT INTO MYTABLEB ( SELECT DISTINCT ...... FROM MYTABLEA )`

Comment: If the duplicates are being introduced by the inserts from Table A, then it seems that a MERGE would be in order. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Comment: @LeighRiffel that is PRECISELY what I needed to know - and it works great!  If you migrate this to an answer, I will happily accept!  Thanks everyone for the input!

Comment: @LeighRiffel: Yeah, I forgot all about MERGE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the duplicates are being introduced by the inserts from Table A, then it seems a [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) would be in order.  A `MERGE` can `INSERT` data when the record does not exist in Table B and `UPDATE` data if the record already exists thus preventing the introduction of duplicates.

FrustratedWithFormsDesign is correct that you probably should have a constraint preventing the introduction of duplicates.  He is also correct in pointing out that this code would probably benefit from Bulk processing.

Phil is correct that if you only need to INSERT data, then a subquery pruning rows from the insert would be preferable.